# How to work with dll's?

Tags: dll

So I have a dll file (coded in?) .Net framework, and I want to know all whats in it and use it. But I have no Idea of dll files, I mean I know they are some kind libraries but could someone explain me how it works? How can I know wich functions dll contains and run them? Please be very specific cause I'm completely blind with dll's.

Comment: question is, why do you want to know? generally speaking to look at the .NET compiled assemblies, you can use a tool like Reflector to reflect the assembly and see what is in it. Alternatively just manually add a reference to the DLL in your project and manually explore it

Comment: This is an awesome question. I remember the day when I was in the same shoes as the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a step back and work through some .Net tutorials.

If it's really a .Net DLL, then you can see what functions it exports in Visual Studio (there's a free edition). **But**, if you have no idea what's in the DLL and you just have the DLL file, that's going to be of very limited use to you, because knowing what the functions are doesn't tell you how they're meant to be used; for that, you want the documentation that goes with the DLL.

Still, though:

1. Run Visual Studio
2. Create a new project (probably doesn't much matter what kind, perhaps a Windows Forms project)
3. In the solution explorer, right-click "References", choose "Browse", and browse to the DLL

Now you can see what functions it offers in the object browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own dll file then you need to create ClassLibrary application in Visual Studio. Class library programs contains classes and they don't have main function inside. So it never creates an .exe , it create a .dll file once you compiled after writing your code.

Then you can add this newly created .dll file into your other application by doing this :

"In the solution explorer, right-click "References", choose "Browse", and browse to the newly created dll". Once it is added in your references list , then you can go to your coding and add that namespace(namespace for the .dll) by "using" statement and you can access all the classes available inside that namespace.

Hope this give you a common understanding. If you are not clear, give comment we will make you to understand more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of C, C++ (and in general, "native" code) DLLs contain *compiled code* -- but they contain **almost no information** *about* the code itself. You can use a tool like [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) to view what is there. 
Every DLL contains an "export table", which is the list of callable functions inside it. However, it doesn't contain any information on *how* to call those functions -- that information is traditionally contained in "header" files (`.h`, `.hpp`, `.hxx`, and the like); those files tell you what functions can be called.

Function headers tell you *how* to call certain functions (based on their names), but they don't tell you *which* DLLs contain them. When you compile your code, the "linker" looks for a `.lib` file that contains the name of every function *and the DLL it resides in*, and it matches up the two in your program to make your executable work.

All of this changes in the world of C# and .NET. Over there, DLLs have **complete** information regarding themselves, so the only thing you need in order to call functions inside a DLL is the DLL itself. They follow a slightly different format, and you need tools like [IL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) (which is probably already on your computer) to view the information inside them. (Visual Studio's Object Browser can do this, too.)

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between native dll's and managed dll's(compiled against .NET). If you have a dll written for .NET framework, then you can use decompiler tools to delve into the library.

[ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is a free and open-source .NET decompiler. It can even create the project file for you! Give it a try.